# Can't write Node.js analog to PHP hash checking

Tags: php, node.js, hash, sha256, hmac

Following PHP lines works great, but I can't do such in Node

```
$secret_key = hash('sha256', XXXX, true);
$hash = hash_hmac('sha256', YYYY, $secret_key);
```

As documentation sais hash() returns raw binary data, but it seems like utf8 string. Trying to do such in Node.js

```
const secret = crypto.createHash('sha256')
const secret_key = secret.update(XXXX).digest('utf8')

const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret_key)
const result = hmac.update(YYYY).digest('hex')
```

So PHP's `$hash` and Node.js `result` are not the same. Have tried secret key with 'hex' with no success. How to reproduce it in Node exactly as in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you leave out the encoding of the first `digest` altogether, then you get equal strings:

```
const secret = crypto.createHash('sha256')
const secret_key = secret.update('XXXX').digest()

const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret_key)
const result = hmac.update('YYYY').digest('hex')

console.log(result);
```

Corresponding PHP code:

```
<?php
$secret_key = hash('sha256', 'XXXX', true);
$hash = hash_hmac('sha256', 'YYYY', $secret_key);

echo $hash;
```

> ```
> PHP:    c4888731de466cefaa5c831b54132d3d9384310eb1be36f77f3f6542266cb307
> NodeJS: c4888731de466cefaa5c831b54132d3d9384310eb1be36f77f3f6542266cb307
> ```

Comment: Thank you! There is no hash.digets() with 'utf8' in documentation, I was confused with `hash.update(/* 'utf8' */)
https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_hash_digest_encoding

Answer (score 0):

I guess your mistake is making node export your secret key as "utf8" instead of a hexadecimal representation.

In PHP your key seems to be presented as hex values as well.

Try using "hex" in the first case as well and see what happens:

```
const secret = crypto.createHash('sha256')
const secret_key = secret.update(XXXX).digest('hex')

const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret_key)
const result = hmac.update(YYYY).digest('hex')
```